# Check if an object parameter is Null in razor view - Index?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In Index view I want to check if an object's parameter is null.
I have done it as following code.

```
<td>            
    @if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Account.Name) == false)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink(item.Account.Name, "../Accounts/Details", new { id = item.Account.AccountID })                
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Account.Name)
    }
</td>
```

And I get this error:

> {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

So how should I check if the parameter in null?

---

1-ActionLink generates error if the object is null but DisplayFor does not.

2-This is in foreach loop in Index view.

Comment: Because `Account` is `null` (you need to check that first)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you So much.

Comment: start to check if item is null then item.Account the access item.Account.Name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @StephenMuecke the problem was solved. Here's the change in code:

```
@if (item.Account != null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Account.Name) == false)
```

The `Account` should have been checked first.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to check item.Account because it is null in some cases:

```
@if (item.Account != null)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Account.Name))
            {
                @Html.ActionLink(item.Account.Name, "../Accounts/Details", new { id = item.Account.AccountID })
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Account.Name)
            }
        }
```

Comment: you are using item.Account.Name in if condition but there is a possibility that your item.Account is null... in that case it will throw null reference exception..

Comment: I mean the answer I have given to my post. @Ankit

Comment: Be aware though, that if you're checking both at once, and account is null, then it'll reach the else statement. where account is mentioned again.